# How to get context for Gilde from interface

Tags: android

I'm trying to use Glide to load a picture. Glide needs context/fragment/activity/view...

I have fragment, and in the fragment i implenet interface. The data that i receive is from the MainActivity and it transfer by the interface.
The data that i transfer is image path, and with this image path i want to load with Glide.

The problem is that i need context/fragment/activity/view for the Glide.

**For example**

```
    public class MyAccountFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener,
                                       ChangeProfileImgDialog.OnPhotoReceivedListener{


      @Override
public void getImagePath(Uri imagePath) {
    if( !imagePath.toString().equals("")){
        mSelectedImageUri = imagePath;
        mSelectedImageBitmap = null;
        Log.d(TAG, "getImagePath: got the image uri: " + mSelectedImageUri);
        Glide.with(**What should i do here **).load(imagePath).into(cvUserProfileImage);
    }
}


@Override
public void getImageBitmap(Bitmap bitmap,Context context) {
    if(bitmap != null){
        mSelectedImageUri = null;
        mSelectedImageBitmap = bitmap;
        Log.d(TAG, "getImageBitmap: got the image bitmap: " + mSelectedImageBitmap);
    }
}

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_account, container, false);
     return v;
  }


     @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Well thats the code, i have tried several things but nothing worked.
I always got null. How can i resolve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the fragment's getContext() method to get your context.  This will be the host activity (same as calling getActivity(), it's just cast as a context).

Neither of these methods will work if called before the fragment's onAttach method has been called.  onAttach will be called when the fragment is attached to your activity.  Before this, it cannot get a context.  I would recommend having your interface method save the uri to a local variable and then you can make the call to load it after or inside of onAttach.

However, if cvUserProfileImage is a part of your fragment, you'll need to do this after you inflate your layout in onCreateView.  Otherwise, it won't have been created yet.  I am not sure where you are getting that variable from.

Code would look something like:

```
public class MyAccountFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener,
        ChangeProfileImgDialog.OnPhotoReceivedListener {

    private Uri mSelectedImageUri;
    private Bitmap mSelectedImageBitmap;
    private ImageView cvUserProfileImage;


    @Override
    public void getImagePath(Uri imagePath) {
        if (!imagePath.toString().equals("")) {
            mSelectedImageUri = imagePath;
            mSelectedImageBitmap = null;
            Log.d(TAG, "getImagePath: got the image uri: " + mSelectedImageUri);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void getImageBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Context context) {
        if (bitmap != null) {
            mSelectedImageUri = null;
            mSelectedImageBitmap = bitmap;
            Log.d(TAG, "getImageBitmap: got the image bitmap: " + mSelectedImageBitmap);
        }
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_account, container, false);

        cvUserProfileImage = v.findViewById(R.Id.cvUserProfileImage);
        if (mSelectedImageUri != null) {
            Glide.with(getContext()).load(mSelectedImageUri).into(cvUserProfileImage);
        } else if (mSelectedImageBitmap != null){
            cvUserProfileImage.setImageBitmap(mSelectedImageBitmap);
        }

        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did "getActivity()" but i get null. I think thats because the fragment is not loaded yet. As you can see the method is before the "onViewCreated"

Comment: Oh, I see.  You can save the url to an instance variable and then load it in OnAttach.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: The cvUserProfileImage like you said, its inflate on the "onCreateView" , so i should create a local virable and save the data on that virable. and then what should i do?

Comment: It doesnt working. I added these line of code. The app is not crashing, but it also not changing the picture.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on the glide line and make sure none of those values is null (view or URL)?  If none of them ar enull, try hardcoding this uri in instead and see fi glide loads this image: https://opensource.google.com/assets/static/images/home/blog/blog_image_1.jpg

If it does, it's likely an issue in the URL you're using.  If it doesn't, it could be that Glide was not configured properly.